# NullPointerException in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

This is my AsyncTask class.

```
class AsyncLoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ListData>> {

    int i = 0;

    protected ArrayList<ListData>[] onPostExecute(ArrayList<ListData>... result) {

        return result;
    }

    protected ArrayList<ListData> doInBackground(Void... parameter) {

        ArrayList<ListData> news = null;

        int[] id = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        String[] title = { "title1", "title2", "title3", "title4", "title5" };
        String[] category = { "category1", "category2", "category3",
                "category4", "category5" };
        int[] image = { R.drawable.pic01, R.drawable.pic02, R.drawable.pic03,
                R.drawable.pic04, R.drawable.pic05, R.drawable.pic06 };

        for (i = 0; i <= id.length - 1; i++) {

            news.add(new ListData(id[i], title[i], category[i], image[i]));

        }

        return news;

    }
}
```

When i'm trying to execute this task i get this error: 
LOG

```
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error     occured while executing doInBackground()
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684): at    android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684): at    java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-24 21:44:51.265: E/AndroidRuntime(7684): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And this is the ListData.java:

```
package com.example.test2;

public class ListData {
int id;
String title;      
String category;          
int image;     


ListData(int _id, String _title, String _category, int _image) {
  id = _id;
  title = _title;
  category = _category;
  image = _image;     

}
```

}

And in MainActivity i'm just executing AsynTask (
    AsyncLoad load = new AsyncLoad(); load.execute();
)

**Please help me to find where i'm wrong!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes. Look at this:

```
ArrayList<ListData> news = null;
```

and then:

```
news.add(new ListData(id[i], title[i], category[i], image[i]));
```

How did you expect that to work? `news` will never have a non-null value, so when you call `news.add` you *will* get a `NullPointerException`. You want something like:

```
List<ListData> news = new ArrayList<ListData>();
```

(Note how I've used `ArrayList` as the concrete implementation, but preferring to generally program to interfaces, I've made the `news` variable itself of type `List<ListData>`.)

Answer (score 1):

You never instantiated your list `news`. You need to do this:

```
ArrayList<ListData> news = new ArrayList<ListData>();
```

Comment: `news` is a variable - there's no such thing as "instantiating" a variable. The variable is initialized, but to null. It's worth trying to separate out the ideas of variables, references, and objects - they are very different concepts, and mixing them up creates confusion.